# Disable passwords when using ssh

Tags: ssh

I have found lots of answered questions on this subject, both here on SE, and elsewhere. But I'm still stuck.

We use mercurial at work, and we have a script (which is outside my control) to clone a repo on my local machine to another location on this same machine. The script does something like this:

```
$ hg clone ssh://user@<local-machine>//<local-repo-location> <local-destination-location>
user@<local-machine>'s password:
```

It requests a password, which breaks the script.

I have created rsa keypair, and copied the public-key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, and also to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 (after reading a post elsewhere). I have set the permissions for these three files to 640.

Even connecting to my local machine using ssh also requests the password:

```
$ ssh user@<local-machine>
user@<local-machine>'s password:
```

I'm trying to configure my local machine such that no password is requested, for both the ssh and repo clone operations. I have asked a colleague to do the same and in his case, no password is requested. Is this a local configuration problem?

Comment: *How* did you generate the rsa keypair? if you'd used `ssh-keygen` it would only have been necessary to copy the public key to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` if you used a non-default name or location for the output file(s) - if so, what did you do with the *private* key? If that has a non-default name and/or location, you will need to pass it to ssh explicitly (either using the `-i` command line option, or via your `.ssh/config` file).

Comment: Shouldn't `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` be `600` permissions?  Per my man page for ssh, "This file is not highly sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by others."

Comment: @MarkStewart I wondered about that myself and did a quick test on an Ubuntu box - setting it to 640 didn't *appear* to break anything, but I guess that may be configuration dependent

Comment: Just in case you already use Ansible at work for deployment, it could take care of propagating the SSH keys to other machines as required: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. For some reason, the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file had multiple entries. When I deleted the rsa files and recreated the key pairs, it worked. Silly me, sorry for wasting everyone's time